# Proving $R/I \otimes_R M \cong_R M/IM$ using UMP and a biadditive map not with exact sequences.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, tensor-decomposition

I want to Understand a paragraph of the proof of $R/I \otimes_R M \cong_R M/IM.$ in example$(8)$ on pg. 370 of Dummit and Foote (third edition)

Here is the example from Dummit & Foote:

> [image]
> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- I do not understand exactly why we need the previous observation (as stated in the book) to say that the map $N \rightarrow (R/I) \otimes_R N$ defined by $n \mapsto 1 \otimes n$ is surjective?

2-why we need $IN$ to be in the kernel?

3- why $1 \otimes a_i n_i = a_i \otimes n_i$?

4- Why the author defined $f$ by that definition?

Could anyone help me answer those questions please?

Comment: The answers to 1-3 mostly follow from the definitions, it'd be useful if you are some more details about where exactly you need help answering those questions.

Comment: @Quimey which definitions exactly I should revise to understand them. Also, I am having hard times understanding what the author is doing in the last paragraph of the first picture I posted. If you could explain that to me I would be very grateful to that.

Comment: For #1, it's the observation to note that $f$ is a surjection is all.  For #2 it's not really that you "need" it in the kernel, it's that it is by definition of your map.  #3 is the bimodule structure, distributing the scalar $a_i$ to the other tensor factor.  For #4, I don't understand what you mean; it's just part of the proof.

Comment: @JohnSamples I feel like this proof is not organized and contain sometimes ideas that can be explained by simpler ways. If you can organize this proof (with including some details)in an answer I would be very grateful for this

Comment: I think the answer given below fills in the few details that aren't included in the book; the proof is very bare-bones logic+definitions, I think you just don't have some of these definitions grasped with facility yet is all.  Why don't you play with tensors a bit more, work out some examples and extra exercises?  That will do more to help your understanding than anything that will be posted here.  I don't mean it in a rude way, I got hung up on this material as well (same book).

Comment: @JohnSamples Why $a_i \otimes n_i = 0$?Is that because $I$ is the identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a useful exercise for you to prove this for yourself rather than to try to follow the proof (and consequently bear the burden of filling in all of the missing details) from a textbook. Toward this end, allow me to provide you with some suggestions that you can use in your proof.

- Observe that by definition, the tensor product gives an $R$-bilinear map $\tau : (R / I) \times M \to (R / I) \otimes_R M$ defined by $\tau(r + I, m) = (r + I) \otimes_R m.$ We will need also an $R$-bilinear map $\varphi : (R / I) \times M \to M/IM.$ **Hint:** for a module $N$ over a commutative ring $S,$ the multiplication map $S \times N \to N$ that sends $(s, n) \mapsto s \cdot n$ is always bilinear.
- Once we have two $R$-bilinear maps $\tau : (R / I) \times M \to (R / I) \otimes_R M$ and $\varphi : (R / I) \times M \to M / IM,$ the universal property of the tensor product gives a *unique* $R$-bilinear map $\psi : (R / I) \otimes_R M \to M / IM$ such that $\psi \circ \tau = \varphi,$ i.e., we have that $\psi[(r + I) \otimes_R m] = \varphi(r + I, m)$ for all $r + I \in R / I$ and $m \in M.$
- Can you find a well-defined $R$-bilinear map $\gamma : M / IM \to (R / I) \otimes_R M$ such that $\psi \circ \gamma$ is the identity map on $M / IM$? **Hint:** there is a "standard" way to give a map $M \to R \otimes_R M.$ If you mimic this idea, you will find exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119824/discussion-on-answer-by-carlo-proving-r-i-otimes-r-m-cong-r-m-im-using-ump-a).

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer that could be expanded if more details are provided

1. You need the previous observation to prove that elements $1\otimes n$ generate the tensor product as an $R$-module, since all of them are in the image and the map is $R$ linear the claim follows.
2. You need that to define a map from a quotient.
3. By definition of tensor product over $R$, $R$-scalars can "jump" from one side to the other of the product.
4. It was probably easier to show the inverse than to prove than the original map is injective.

Comment: Can you organize the proof that is given in the book and include it (with simple explanations)in an answer?

Comment: Can you show me the details of finding the inverse?

Comment: The inverse is the function $g$ defined in the book. In order to verify that you can _explicitely_ compute $fg$ and $gf$.

Comment: All the missing details are quite straightforward as @john suggested in the comment above

Comment: Why $a_i \otimes n_i = 0$?

Comment: @hard, if $a_i$ is in $I,$ then $a_i \equiv 0 \text{ (mod } I).$